# How to determine the color html code of a region in an image

Tags: html, css, gimp

Is there a way to determine the html code of the color of a section in an image.
In my case I have a logo in png format and I want to know the color's html code of a section in the logo so that the menu items have the same color.

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean with color html code? Do you mean the hexadecimal code that represents the code?

Comment: @Maurice, whatever I can use in css (hexa or rgb)

Comment: @Maurice I added the tags for html and css just so that it is clear for other people

Comment: Am not sure why all this complication: Open the image using gimp and pick the color, then use it ... or inspect the element and use the color picker of Chrome or FF

Comment: @Temani, you are right it is very easy. I am completely new to gimp the first time using it. I am adding steps i used to do this for other people.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps that worked for me:

1. open the image in gimp
2. Make sure the toolbox dialog is visible. If it is not use "Windows -> new Toolbox".
3. Make sure The colors dialog is visible. If it is not "Windows -> Dockable Dialogs -> Coulours"
4. Select the eye drop icon in the toolbox dialog (when you hover it it will show this text: Color Picker Tool: Set Coulours from image pixels).
5. click on the area of the image that you want to get the color code (the code will automatically show at the bottom of the coulors dialog).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you wanted to get the color of what you see on your screen. Then perform these steps.

1. Take a screenshot of what you see and paste it in mspaint.
2. Then use colour picker from tools menu and click on the place for which you wanted to know the colour.
3. Then under color menu use edit Colors option.
4. There in the edit Colors menu in the right side you will get the right color coordinates.

Now use editors like Visual Studio Code to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In line with [Temani's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803260/how-to-determine-the-color-html-code-of-a-region-in-an-image#comment90563123_51803260), keep it simple.

**For Chrome**: Right click anywhere, click "Inspect". If you don't see any colors on the bottom left, click on `element.style` and type something like `color: black;`. Then, click on the little black box that appears next to the color and click on your image. `color: black;` will now become `color: #fea43d;` or whatever the color you clicked is.

**For Firefox**: Right click anywhere, click "Inspect Element". If you don't see any colors on the right, click on `element` and type something like `color: black;`. Then, click on the little black circle that appears next to the color, click the eyedropper tool on the bottom left of the box that pops up, and click on your image. `color: black;` will now become `color: #fea43d;` or whatever the color you clicked is.

Answer (score 0):

> For html elements, you can right click on which color you want and
>   'inspect' it. You can find the color code in CSS.

For images in the pages:

> - You can install color picker extension/plugin for your browser, in which you just right click and get color code in hex or rgb formats.

OR

> - Download the image, open it in any photo editors which can read color.

Answer (score -1):

@Karim maybe I can help you with your problem.
Here is the link - https://imagecolorpicker.com, I found yesterday while exploring the internet and I am damn sure that it will definitely help you.
just upload your Image file(or anything which is a screenshot, etc) or any websites URL to below mentioned the website and click on submit button.
Then your image or your uploaded content will appear with all its color details written at the adjacent side. You can click on your image at any pixel(position) and the details of color will be updated for that pixel(position) in HEX, RGB, HSV(HSL)
Here is the [Image] - : https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5elS.png for your reference.

May this will help You.